# Failed to insert data

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to add data to a MySQL Server database.

Here is the code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.3.173\hidp;Initial Catalog=HIDP;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=intranet;Password=kikapu;APP=Intranet")
    Dim sql As String = "Insert into [RAVARIAS].[StockMovimentos] ([CodHospital], [utilizador], [servico], [CodDevice], [CodConsumivel], [TipoMovimento], [DtMovimento], [Qtd]) values (@CodHospital, @utilizador, @servico, @CodDevice, @CodConsumivel, @TipoMovimento, @DtMovimento, @Qtd)"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodHospital", Session("Codhospital"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@utilizador", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@servico", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodDevice", DropDownList3.SelectedItem)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodConsumivel", DropDownList4.SelectedItem)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoMovimento", DropDownList2.SelectedItem)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtMovimento", Calendar1.SelectedDate)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qtd", TextBox4.Text)
    connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    DropDownList2.ClearSelection()
    DropDownList3.ClearSelection()
    DropDownList4.ClearSelection()
    Calendar1.SelectedDates.Clear()
End Sub
```

When I click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: Sounds like a debugging expedition. Step through your code and see what happens.

Comment: This is a little vague, what do you mean "nothing happens"? Do you not see the update in the MySQL server? What is supposed to happen that isn't?

Comment: When I click on the Button, the data is not inserted into the database and the data that I wrote before clicking the Button doesn't get cleared.

Comment: You have not created a Complete example. Please review [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have not shown you're calling this sub.

Comment: Sounds like the handler isn't firing not that the code is not working.